# Error in deploying Django app on Google cloud using appengine "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable"

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-settings, django-deployment

I am trying to deploy my own django app on google cloud. I'm following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine)
by Google Cloud to deploy the app. I have changed the settings.py file of my app according to the settings.py file of the sample app provided by Google.

I have created a Django environment file as a Secret Manager secret by following the same documentation. its format is

```
echo DATABASE_URL=postgres://DATABASE_NAME:DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD@//cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_ID/CRRathod > .env
echo GS_BUCKET_NAME=my-portfolio-361305_crrathod-bucket >> .env
echo SECRET_KEY=$(cat/dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alpha:]'| fold -w 50 | head -n1) >> .env
```

After entering next command as documentation python manage.py makemigrations I'm getting errors as

```
(env) C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog>python manage.py makemigrations
Invalid line: echo DATABASE_URL=postgres://DATABASE_NAME:DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD@//cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_ID/CRRathod > .env
Invalid line: echo GS_BUCKET_NAME=my-portfolio-361305_crrathod-bucket >> .env
Invalid line: echo SECRET_KEY=$(cat/dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alpha:]'| fold -w 50 | head -n1) >> .env
Invalid line: echo DATABASE_URL=postgres://CRRathod:CRroot@123@//cloudsql/my-portfolio-361305:asia-south1:crrathod/CRRathod > .env
Invalid line: echo GS_BUCKET_NAME=my-portfolio-361305_crrathod-bucket >> .env
Invalid line: echo SECRET_KEY=$(cat/dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alpha:]'| fold -w 50 | head -n1) >> .env
Invalid line: echo DATABASE_URL=postgres://CRRathod:CRroot@123@//cloudsql/my-portfolio-361305:asia-south1:crrathod/CRRathod > .env
Invalid line: echo GS_BUCKET_NAME=my-portfolio-361305_crrathod-bucket >> .env
Invalid line: echo SECRET_KEY=$(cat/dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alpha:]'| fold -w 50 | head -n1) >> .env
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 403, in get_value
    value = self.ENVIRON[var_name]
  File "C:\Users\LONAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 455, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\caches.py", line 64, in check_file_based_cache_is_absolute
    for alias, config in settings.CACHES.items():
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\LONAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\crrathod\settings.py", line 59, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 197, in __call__
    return self.get_value(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\Portfolio-blog\env\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 407, in get_value
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg) from exc
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
```

I'm hiding some data here as security precaution and representing its pattern only.

**settings.py file**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import io
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import environ
from google.cloud import secretmanager

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# [START gaestd_py_django_secret_config]
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False))
env_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")

if os.path.isfile(env_file):
    # Use a local secret file, if provided

    env.read_env(env_file)
# [START_EXCLUDE]
elif os.getenv("TRAMPOLINE_CI", None):
    # Create local settings if running with CI, for unit testing

    placeholder = (
        f"SECRET_KEY=a\n"
        f"DATABASE_URL=sqlite://{os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')}"
    )
    env.read_env(io.StringIO(placeholder))
# [END_EXCLUDE]
elif os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT", None):
    # Pull secrets from Secret Manager
    project_id = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT")

    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    settings_name = os.environ.get("SETTINGS_NAME", "django_settings")
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{settings_name}/versions/latest"
    payload = client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

    env.read_env(io.StringIO(payload))
else:
    raise Exception("No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found.")
# [END gaestd_py_django_secret_config]



SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env("DEBUG")

# [START gaestd_py_django_csrf]
# SECURITY WARNING: It's recommended that you use this when
# running in production. The URL will be known once you first deploy
# to App Engine. This code takes the URL and converts it to both these settings formats.
APPENGINE_URL = env("APPENGINE_URL", default=None)
if APPENGINE_URL:
    # Ensure a scheme is present in the URL before it's processed.
    if not urlparse(APPENGINE_URL).scheme:
        APPENGINE_URL = f"https://{APPENGINE_URL}"

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [urlparse(APPENGINE_URL).netloc]
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [APPENGINE_URL]
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
# [END gaestd_py_django_csrf]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'portpolio.apps.PortpolioConfig',
    'CRblogs.apps.CrblogsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_social_share',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'crrathod.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS':  [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'crrathod.wsgi.application'


# Database
# [START db_setup]
# [START gaestd_py_django_database_config]
# Use django-environ to parse the connection string
DATABASES = {"default": env.db()}

# If the flag as been set, configure to use proxy
if os.getenv("USE_CLOUD_SQL_AUTH_PROXY", None):
    DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] = "127.0.0.1"
    DATABASES["default"]["PORT"] = 8088

# [END gaestd_py_django_database_config]
# [END db_setup]

# Use a in-memory sqlite3 database when testing in CI systems
# TODO(glasnt) CHECK IF THIS IS REQUIRED because we're setting a val above
if os.getenv("TRAMPOLINE_CI", None):
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
        }
    }



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

# STATICFILES_DIRS =[
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# ]

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

I'm not able to solve the error after lots of attempts. please help me thank you

Comment: Here could be a couple things to try, if you haven't already, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137290/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-set-the-secret-key-environment-vari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by removing some extra spaces from my secret manager file i.e. .env file
as I mentioned in the question previously my secret manager code was

```
echo DATABASE_URL=postgres://DATABASE_USERNAME:DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD@//cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_ID/CRRathod > .env
echo GS_BUCKET_NAME=my-portfolio-361305_crrathod-bucket >> .env
echo SECRET_KEY=$(cat/dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alpha:]'| fold -w 50 | head -n1) >> .env
```

I had changed it to

```
echo DATABASE_URL=postgres://DATABASE_USERNAME:DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD@//cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_ID/CRRathod>.env
echo GS_BUCKET_NAME=my-portfolio-361305_crrathod-bucket>>.env
echo SECRET_KEY=$(cat/dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alpha:]'| fold -w 50 | head -n1)>>.env
```

Just removed all extra spaces

Then set the secret key value from the terminal as
`set SECRET_KEY=my_secret_key_value`

Comment: I had to take this rout to get it to work.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687306/reading-django-settings-from-google-cloud-platforms-secret-manager-does-not-wor   The 'echo" is  also removed.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial instructs the user to create a `.env` file - and so it is easy to misunderstand that and think you need to copy the lines shown directly into a new `.env` file.

Instead, you need to run the `echo` lines directly on the command line which in turn create the `.env` file and populate it with the required syntax used by subsequent steps in the tutorial.

If you created a problematic `.env` file and experience `Invalid line` error output during the `makemigrations` step - delete the `django_settings` secret:

```
gcloud secrets delete django_settings
```

Now go back to the top of the [Create Django environment file as a Secret Manager secret](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run#create-django-environment-file-as-a-secret) section - and copy those echo lines directly onto the command line and run them.

You can now check the contents of the .env file:

```
cat .env
```

You can now recreate the `django_settings` secret and the remainder of the relevant steps in that section. Once completed, you can skip back down and try to run `makemigrations` again.